# Working with layer control in a folium map

Tags: python, maps, layer, folium

I'm trying to create an interactive map with the folium package in Python. In order to do it I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Circuit Latitude Longitude Date    
L2RC 41.36394 -8.550200 15/02
L21M 41.22638 -8.693360 15/02
LBXP 41.15796 -8.610030 17/03
L2RC 41.36394 -8.550200 02/08
LERM 41.23865 -8.531550 17/03
LCAN 41.14016 -8.634990 18/03
LARE 41.19195 -8.556460 05/08
LCAR 41.05805 -8.563920 05/08
LBXP 41.15786 -8.600700 09/03
LBAG 41.18931 -8.526040 12/04
```

My goal is to plot this map and have kind of a filter box based on the circuit and date attribute of the dataset. For instance, if 15/02 and L2RC is checked in the filter, the map should only show the points with both those attributes. I think the only way this can be done is through layer control and feature group.
I have already managed to do this for the circuit attribute. The map I get looks like this:
[image]

The code to get this is the following, `unique_circuitos` is a list with the unique values in the attribute circuit of the dataframe and I create a feature groupe for each one of the them:

```
feature_group=[]
        for i in range(len(unique_circuitos)):
            index=str(i)
            name="fg"+index
            feature_group.append(name)
            feature_group[i]=folium.FeatureGroup(name=unique_circuitos[i])
        


for j in range(len(unique_circuitos)):      
        for i in range(len(df)):
            if df.iloc['circuito',i]==unique_circuitos[j]:
                feature_group[j].add_child(folium.CircleMarker(
                    location=(df.iloc['latitude',i], df.iloc['longitude',i]),
                    radius=2,
                    fill=True,
                    color=cores[i],
                    #fill_opacity=0.7
                ))
```

Now I want to do the same for the date attribute but I'm not quite sure how to do this, since I want to have something like the image above:
[image]

If anyone could help me I would be quite thankful, even if it is to tell me that it is impossible to have this feature with folium.
Thanks!